# an alarm that has passed the time rings again when I open the app / kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
var intentAlarm = Intent(applicationContext, MySound::class.java)
var pendingintent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(applicationContext, 111, intentAlarm, 0)
var alarm: AlarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

// alarm
var calender: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
    set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16)
    set(Calendar.MINUTE, 3)
    set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
 }

alarm.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calender.timeInMillis, pendingintent)`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Unlike other alarms, the system is free to reschedule this type of alarm to happen out of order with any other alarms, even those from the same app. This will clearly happen when the device is idle (since this alarm can go off while idle, when any other alarms from the app will be held until later), but may also happen even when not idle. Note that the OS will allow itself more flexibility for scheduling these alarms than regular exact alarms, since the application has opted into this behavior.

So even you have set setExactAndAllowWhileIdle, the system does not assure to make the alarm go off at the exact time yo have set.